# Writing a Custom Gateway Error Response using a mapping template in VTL for AWS

Tags: mapping, aws-api-gateway, response, custom-error-pages, vtl

I'm writing a mapping template for an AWS API Gateway integration response to return a custom error output format.

My function looks like this:

```
{
    "gw_code":"$gw_code",
    "er_code":"$er_code",
    "code":"$gw_code" + "-" + "$er_code",
    "developerMessage":"$developerMessage"
    "message":"$message"
    "gw_msg":"$code
              $developerMessage"
}
#set ($er_num = "200")
#set ($er_msg = "ACCESS_DENIED")
#if($code == "403-001" && $developerMessage == "Unauthorized")
    // Ignore
#else
    {
        "code" : "403-001",
        "developerMessage" : "Unauthorized."
    }
#end
```

But the URL prints an internal server error as the output:
`{"message": "Internal server error"}`

I re-read the [VTL documentation guide](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference.html) and attempted to modify the code by boiling it down to this:

```
#set($messageOverride = "foo")
{
    #if($status == "403-001" && $developerMessage = "Unauthorized")
        // Ignore
    #else
        #if($inputRoot.toString().contains("error"))
            "code" : "403-001",
            "developerMessage" : "Unauthorized."
        #end
    #end
#end
}
```

But the internal server error is still showing up and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code is a big improvement from the first, however it still needs some work.

Your function should look something like this:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
    #if($status == "403-001" && $developerMessage = <TBD>)
        // Ignore
    #else
        #if($inputRoot.toString().contains("error"))
            #set($context.responseOverride.status = 403)
            #set($context.requestOverride.header.devMessage = $message1Override)
        #end
    #end
#end
```

I haven't tested it, but in theory, it should work.